# C# - Transparent Form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, transparent

I currently have a Form with all the desired effects except one. The current form consists out of a menustrip at the top with a panel underneath which contains labels and pictureboxes. When the form is launched the menustrip is not visible, it only becomes visible while the user presses the 'Alt'-button and disappears in the same manner.

The panel will have a background-image with a transparent background (.PNG). This image will become the main layout of the form as I set the borderstyle to none. Now the problem is that the form still has the white/grayish background underneath the panel.

Now my question is how do I make the form transparent so the image on the panel becomes the main layout rather than just the image with the forms backcolor underneath it. I do not want to use the Opacity property as I want the panel to be visible 100%.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Assuming WinForms.

You can do this, but you **cannot** make the edges semi-transparent.

Try this.

On the form, set the following properties:

```
BackColor = Color.Lime;
TransparencyKey = Color.Lime;
```

This will make the form transparent. Then set the backgroundimage:

```
BackgroundImage = myImage:
```

The parts of the backgroundimage that is also `Color.Lime`will also get transparent.

If you also want to get rid of the `Forms` borders, add this line as well:

```
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you for the swift reply and detailed explanation. I cannot believe it is this simple! Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. I did the same thing once when I made a splash screen for an application.

Comment: Thanks, it works well. One question, I notice that if I use drawstring to draw some text to a transparent label on a transparent form, there will be a lime(or any color used as TransparencyKey) jaggies around the text. Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Be careful when you will choosing backcolor. Chose a Backcolor to differ from your text, images, and any control's color that mean choose a color that you will never going to use in your Form and I think Fuchsia/ lime will be the best choice.For choosing a backcolor codes are below:

```
this.BackColor = Color.Fuchsia;
```

and then Make that color to Transparent by using that codes:

```
TransparencyKey = Color.Fuchsia;
```

Comment: Why chooose a color you will never going to use?

Comment: Because if you do use that color somewhere else, and you've set it to be the `TransparencyKey` then it will also be made transparent. Sort of like if the weather man wore a bright green suit in front of the green screen.

Comment: yup coz we are going transparent a color when you will use color which you use in form  then that text or image will also be transparent

Comment: you can do with form properties as well rather than code i guess.