# C# Make a form's background transparent (to display .png background with half-transparent pixels)

Tags: c#, winforms, background, visual-studio-2013

PNG image have transparent parts and I want this image as background for my form.
I've set `ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor` to `true` and used `this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;` but this is just not working at all, the back color appears solid gray when im starting app. Even if I set **BackColor** to **Transparent** in **Properties->Appearence**. I can see it Transparent in form design preview but it still appears solid gray when Im start the application.
Playing with `TransparencyKey` also gaves me a bad results - the half-transparent pixels of PNG image became colored with `TransparencyKey` color and i can't use Transparent color for `TransparencyKey`. Looking for some help.
EXAMPLE:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9p6N.jpg

Comment: Have you seen answer here at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314215/c-sharp-transparent-form

Comment: iv'e added image to the question, so you can see the problem with TransparencyKey

Comment: You need per-pixel alpha transparency, not directly supported in Winforms because it is incompatible with lots of controls in the toolbox.  The kind that are implemented by Windows, they get transparent as well.  Using a WPF window is the logical approach.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `TransparencyKey` incorrectly. The idea behind this property is that the color specified as the `TransparencyKey` will be transparent. E.g. if you set `myForm.TransparencyKey = Color.Red` anything that is red will be transparent. However, if the shade of red is different than the one described as `Color.Red` it won't be transparent.

Or, to put it another way, it will result in a transparent background:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 0);
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

But this will not be transparent:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(99, 0, 0);
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

So now if your image has white background and you set `this.TransparencyKey = Color.White` only white parts of the image will be transparent. But if there are any grayish, white-ish areas you will see this color instead of transparent background.

If that's the case you may need to edit the image to be sure the background is everywhere of the same color.