# Click on VLC player Pause/Play

Tags: c#, winforms, vlc

I develop an application that use VLCdotNET to create media player. Need to make an action that allow to click on video, the video can play or pause like a video on Youtube. Anybody has any solution? I tried to make event click on VLC but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The sample application included with the library contains an example of how to accomplish what you are looking for: https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/blob/master/src/Samples/Vlc.DotNet.Forms.Samples/Sample.cs

Comment: Sorry. I've read this but this's not i am looking for. I dont need a button to make video play and pause! I need raise an event when i click on screen of video and it can play or pause like Youtube.

Comment: Why not add a transparent form or control on top of your window? You could then catch the event because it does not look like the VLC control is giving you that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314215/c-sharp-transparent-form?rq=1

Comment: Thanks! the transparent panel is work for me! :D.  Now, i face to separate form with 2 panel with 1 panel is video panel and 1 panel for controls of video. How can i set the panel with control with fix height and the video panel with form height- controls panel height?

Comment: For that just overlay the transparent panel and subscribe to the base's sizing events. In the handler just resize the transparent panel.

Comment: @HoàngĐỗHuy hi, i faced the same problem. how do you set the panel to transparent ? because when i try to set transparent it took the form background color. pls help or maybe follow my post thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710806/how-to-set-transparent-opacity-to-panel