# Transparent Control through the Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been facing an issue recently.

I need to create a transparent panel that shows what is Behind the form, not the Form.

 For example, if I am running my application on my desktop; something like [this](https://gyazo.com/41a097c742b562fbc0d399d5f0d96752), I will see my desktop from where where the panel is.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You mean, like a glass?

Comment: If you can show us what you've tried, maybe we can help...

Comment: @ThadeuFernandes Correct :) , and RichardEverett the only progress I have gotten to is setting the backcolor to Color.Transparent and that is not what my goal is :\

Comment: I think that this can be a way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314215/c-sharp-transparent-form

Comment: @ThadeuFernandes after some tweaking, I got that to work :) I suggest you answer so I can accept it

Comment: You can create a Form and set both `BackColor` and `TransparencyKey` properties to `Color.Magenta`. This way you will have a transparent form which also mouse click pass through the form. If you want to be able to handle click on transparent area, use `Color.Red`. [Transparent Windows Form without transparent Title Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783183/transparent-windows-form-without-transparent-title-bar/32783251#32783251)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a background color then use the TransparencyKey in properties to make this color transparent.

Reference: [C# - Transparent Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314215/c-sharp-transparent-form)